# How to catch Delete key event in tree panel controller

Tags: extjs

I have a tree panel `view` (defined as `FilesEditorNavigTree`) and a `controller`. In a controller I want to catch `Delete` key event in order to perform some procedure. I tried to do it like this:

```
...
init:function(){
    this.control({
        'FilesEditorNavigTree':{
             specialkey:function(a, b){
                 alert(b.keyCode); // just for testing reasons
             }
```

But it has no effect.

Comment: I think people will be able to help you a bit better if we can see your whole program.

Comment: I think, I narrowed down the whole problem to what really matters. `view` is ok, `controller` is ok - other methods like itemclick etc. are working. So, threre is no reason to present here the whole program. The formulation of the problem is quite obvious - a user clicks on a tree node or selects multiple nodes, then hits Delete button - and this is what I want to catch.

Comment: how about "itemkeydown" listener? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-event-itemkeydown

Comment: @Tyr I will check it in a minute

Comment: The only problem I see - is still how to catch Delete event, now inside itemkeydown listener =)

Comment: See the docs for `itemkeydown`, it passes the event: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-itemkeydown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rowkeydown listener of the treepanel view.

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners : {
        rowkeydown : function(view, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 46) { 
                console.log('hit delete');
            }
        }
    }
});
```